# » dürfen überholt werden«

Tags: grammatical-case, phrase, future

Es gibt folgendes Straßenschild:

[image]

Warum steht auf dem Schild »dürfen [die Traktoren] überholt **werden**« statt »dürfen überholt **sein**«?

Ich verstehe ganz klar die Sinne und die Grammatik, aber warum wird hier das Futur genutzt?

Comment: +1 für das  Zeichen. Hatte keine Ahnung, dass es einen code point für Traktoren gibt. Wie das Zeichen wohl in fett aussieht? Bulldozer?

Comment: @Philipp: normal: , kursiv: **, fett: ****

Comment: Das Zeichen wird in meinem Browser nur als leeres Kästchen dargestellt.

Comment: @Takkat: Nicht nur in Deinem.

Comment: Erst aus Deinem Kommentar zu Stephies Antwort erschließt sich mir, was eigentlich Deine Frage ist, bzw. wie Du darauf kommst, es solle "dürfen überholt sein" heißen (wörtliche Übersetzung der englischen Phrase). Das gehört m.E. in die Frage.

Comment: @Takkat: Dafür im Android-Client sogar als farbiges Icon.

Comment: @Takkat Scheint auch was mit dem OS zu tun zu haben. Ich sitze mal an Rechnern mit Windows 8.1, mal an W7-Kisten, jeweils mit dem aktuellen Firefox. Auf den 7ern geht es mir wie Dir, die 8er hingegen zeigen das Symbol an. Und auch Chrome auf W7 kann es nicht.

Comment: Das hängt von den installierten Schriftsätzen ab. Bei vielen Schriftarten sind obskure UTF8 Zeichen nicht dabei, bei anderen hingegen schon.

Comment: Das "Tractor-Emoji" (U+1F69C) wurde erst in 2010 mit Unicode 6.0 eingeführt. Ob man schon den neuen Schriftsatz installiert hat, kann man z.B. hier testen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_and_Map_Symbols.

Comment: @Philipp, "UTF8-Zeichen" ergibt nicht viel Sinn.

Comment: @CarstenS Verzeihung, bin kein IT-ler. Also, in UTF8 gibt es mehr Codes für Zeichen als z.B. ascii. Unterschiedliche Schriftarten unterstützen unterschiedlich viele dieser Zeichen.

Comment: @Philipp, ich muss um Verzeihung bitten, ich habe wohl vergessen, dass nicht jeder auf SE ein Computermensch ist. Du meinst [Unicode](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)-Zeichen, [UTF-8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) ist lediglich eine Art, einen Unicode-Text in eine Bytefolge umzusetzen. Wenn ich beispielsweise in HTML `&#128668;` schreibe, stelle ich damit das selbe Zeichen dar, ohne dass UTF-8 im Spiel gewesen wäre. (Und jemand anders wird jetzt Ungenauigkeiten in meinen Bezeichnung herausstellen ;)

Comment: @CarstenS Danke für die Erklärung! Genau, ich meinte Unicode. Mit den technischen Details kenne ich mich nicht aus. Kann man U+1F69C korrekterweise als „code point für das Traktorensymbol” bezeichnen, oder ist das falsch ausgedrückt?

Comment: Diese Frage ist imho off-topic und könnte recht einfach mit einer Deklinationstabelle und einem Wörterbuch beantwortet werden. Kann man euch so leicht mit einem Emoji "kaufen"? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In einem Fall (**überholt werden**) geht es darum, was andere mit dem Traktor machen dürfen (sie dürfen ihn überholen).
Im anderen Fall (**überholt sein**) geht es um einen Zustand des Traktors, über den etwas ausgesagt wird. (Der Zustand wird zugelassen.) Die anderen Verkehrsteilnehmer spielen in diesem Fall keine Rolle.

---

Das Verb »überholen« hat zwei Bedeutungen:

1. Bei einer Überholung einer Maschine wird die Maschine gewartet. Das heißt, defekte und abgenutzte Teile werden durch neue Teile ersetzt, alle Lager werden mit frischem Öl geschmiert, der Schmutz wird entfernt. Eventuell wird die Maschine auch poliert und neu lackiert.

Da auch ein Traktor eine Maschine ist, kann man auch einen Traktor überholen, und damit eine Wartung meinen.

2. Das Überholen ist im Straßenverkehr jener Vorgang, bei dem ein Fahrzeug, das hinter einem anderen herfährt, nach links ausschert, beschleunigt, und an dem ehemals vorausfahrenden Fahrzeug vorbeifährt. Alternativ kann dieser Vorgang auch aus einer Annäherung eines schnelleren Fahrzeuges an ein langsameres geschehen, ohne dass eine zusätzliche Beschleunigung stattfindet. Ausschlaggebend ist, dass ein schnelleres Fahrzeug an dem langsameren vorbeifährt.

Da Traktoren nicht für hohe Geschwindigkeit gebaut sind, werden sie sehr oft überholt, wobei in diesem Fall das Vorbeifahren eines anderen Fahrzeuges gemeint ist.

Wenn nun auf einem Schild steht:

> Traktoren dürfen überholt werden.

Dann kann das, ohne auf den Kontext Rücksicht zu nehmen, Folgendes bedeuten:

1. Es ist erlaubt, abgenutzte Teile von Traktoren auszutauschen, es ist auch erlaubt sie zu schmieren, zu polieren und neu zu lackieren.
2. Es ist erlaubt, an langsam fahrenden Traktoren vorbeizufahren.

In der Realität (steht auf einem Verkehrsschild) ist der Kontext völlig klar, und man weiß, dass man nach diesem Schild – vorausgesetzt alle anderen Bedingungen lassen es zu – mit dem eigenen Fahrzeug an einem Traktor vorbeifahren darf.

Stünde aber auf dem Schild:

> Traktoren dürfen überholt sein.

Dann handelt es sich um ein Zustandspassiv. Hier wird keine Aussage darüber gemacht, was andere mit einem Traktor machen dürfen, sondern hier wird eine Erlaubnis über einen Zustand des Traktors erteilt.

Hier lässt sogar der Kontext zwei Bedeutungen zu:

1. Auf diesem Straßenabschnitt sind auch solche Traktoren zugelassen, deren abgenutzte Teile erneuert wurden, und an denen andere Wartungsarbeiten durchgeführt wurden.
2. Auf diesem Straßenabschnitt dürfen auch solche Traktoren (weiter-)fahren, die bereits von anderen Fahrzeugen überholt wurden.

Beide Hinweise sind absurd, daher steht dieser Satz auf keinem Verkehrszeichen.

**Nachtrag:**

Der Begriff »überholt sein« hat noch eine dritte Bedeutung: Mit einem Traktor, der überholt ist, kann auch ein veraltetes Model gemeint sein. In dieser Bedeutung wird die Phrase häufig mit den Worten »schon« und »längst« ergänzt:

> Der Traktor von Hans ist bereits 30 Jahre alt und entspricht schon lange nicht mehr dem Stand der Technik. Er ist *schon längst* überholt.

Ein Traktor, der frisch aus der Werkstatt kommt, wo er gerade überholt wurde, kann ein auch längst überholtes Model sein, und auf der Straße sogar von anderen Traktoren überholt werden.

Comment: Für Englisch Sprechende hier noch die Übersetzungen: "Traktoren dürfen überholt werden" = "Tractors are allowed to be passed [or overhauled]". "Traktoren dürfen überholt sein" = "Tractors are allowed to have been overhauled [or overpassed]."

Comment: Mal wieder in epischer Breite Punkte abgehandelt, die offenkundig gar nicht zur Debatte standen.

Answer (score 14):

Das ist kein <del>**Futur**</del>, sondern **Passiv**:

> Es ist (ja wem eigentlich?) erlaubt, die Traktoren zu überholen.

Setzt man die Konstruktion ins Passiv, dann

> ...dürfen die Traktoren überholt werden

und die Frage *für wen diese Erlaubnis gilt* wird hinfällig.

Comment: Aber warum nicht _sein_? z.B. die Traktoren dürfen überholt sein ;-) They can _be_ overtaken.

Comment: @Interface Unknown: Weil der Text deutsch ist und nicht englisch.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Because the action of overtaking a certain type of vehicle is permitted - restricting a general "no overtaking allowed" sign. It's a question of traffic safety, not of the state of the tractors.

Comment: @Stephie I understand the idea of the Schield, as well as the restrictions which it conveys. What I'm embarassed with: is the usage of werden which looks clearly "would" to me instead of sein/be.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Then you should go back to the differences between German and English passive forms - we can't solve wrong associations in your mind and especially auxillary verbs can't be translated 1:1.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. I though the passive forms are the same, but it looks they are not. Still alot to learn...))

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown You are very welcome - glad we could clear this up!

Comment: Du könntest vielleicht hinzufügen, dass das Schild wie ein regulärer Satz gelesen werden kann, wenn man das Traktorsymbol durch *Traktoren* ersetzt.

Comment: Passive voice in the narrower sense is *dynamic passive*. But it's similar in meaning to *stative passive*, which can be assembled by using *be* as a copula and the past participle as an adjective. "The renovated house" → "the house is [= has been] renovated". This works the same way in German. The difference is that in English this is generalised to the dynamic passive: "Someone renovates the house" → "the house is [= gets] renovated". In German it is never done this way; *werden* must always be used instead of *sein*, whereas in English using *get* is optional and only done for clarity.

Comment: @HansAdler "_werden_ must always be used instead of _sein_" (re: passive voice)  – thank you, Hans! It looks that I missed that part at Spachkurs@VHS. This is actually a very laconic answer to my question. When asking the OQ, I was seeking for the explanation simply comparing DE with EN. Now I see there's a strict rule. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Von der deutschen Grammatik werden zwei Passivformen anerkannt: Das *Zustandspassiv*, das in der Regel mit *sein* gebildet wird, und das *Vorgangspassiv*, das in der Regel mit *werden* gebildet **wird.** (Und in diesen Sätzen zur Anwendung gekommen ist.)

Das Vorgangspassiv beschreibt einen Vorgang. Buidogs (»Traktoren« ist ein reichlich preußisches Wort*) *werden* überholt, das dauert je nach Geschwindigkeitsunterschied ein paar Sekunden. Es beschreibt, was *gerade geschieht.*

Das Zustandspassiv beschreibt den Zustand, der nach einem Vorgangspassiv erreicht werden kann. Nachdem ich also den Buidog überholt habe, *ist* er überholt. Es beschreibt also, was *bereits geschehen ist.*

Allein aus diesen Kontexten heraus sollte klar sein, warum *dürfen überholt sein* zwar grammatikalisch korrekt, aber sinnlos wäre.

---

*Das soll heißen, dass es in meiner Gegend Bayerns nicht verwendet wird, und wer es verwendet, sofort das Etikett »Saubreiß« aufgedrückt bekommt. Anderswo im bairischen Sprachraum mag die Verwendung anders sein (siehe Huberts Kommentar).

Gestern Abend habe ich zufällig mitbekommen, dass *Bulldog* ursprünglich ein Markenname der Firma Lanz war, der in Bayern generalisiert wurde. Bulldogs anderer Firmen heißen demnach offiziell *Traktor.*

Comment: +1 für den 'Bulldog', danke!

Comment: »Traktor« ist nicht preußisch, sondern lateinisch: Das Verb »trahere« bedeutet »ziehen, schleppen«. Ein Traktor ist daher jemand (oder etwas), der etwas zieht. Wörtlich also ein »Zieher« oder »Schlepper«. Ich bin in der Steiermark aufgewachsen und lebe in Wien, also doch einige hundert Kilometer vom Land der Preußen entfernt, und ich kenne kein anderes Wort für »Traktor«, das hier in Österreich auch nur annähernd ähnlich häufig verwendet werden würde. Auf Platz zwei in der Verwendungshäufigkeit, aber bereits weit abgeschlagen, liegt »Zugmaschine«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du darfst (und sollst!) den Bulldog als Alternative zum Traktor als bayerische Befindlichkeit deuten. Ich habe bei uns im Westen Oberbayerns noch nie jemanden »Traktor« sagen hören. Wie das weiter östlich aussieht (Miesbach, Traunstein) kann ich naturgemäß nicht sagen.

Comment: Der »Bulldog« reicht bis auf die Schwäbische Alb (BW). Und ich (original aus Norddeutschland) lese das Schild als »*Trecker* dürfen überholt werden«.

Comment: Ich wusste bislang nicht, dass »Bulldog« auch ein Synonym für »Traktor« ist. Ich kannte das Wort bisher nur als englisches Wort für jene Hunderasse, die auf deutsch »Bulldogge« heißt. Das Wort »Trecker« habe ich schon gehört, es wird von österreichischen Bauern aber nicht verwendet. Da man in Österreich bei der Aussprache von T und D in manchen Fällen keinen großen Unterschied macht, dachte ich, als ich das Wort zum ersten Mal hörte, man würde es mit D schreiben: »Drecker«, und hielt das Wort anfangs für die abwertende Bezeichnung für einen Traktor, der auf der Straße Dreck hinterlässt.

Comment: _Ackerschlepper_ gibt es auch noch.

Comment: @ospalh, sogar noch etwas weiter bis ins Schwäbische des Nordschwarzwalds - das Gefährt heißt hier einfach [Bulldog](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanz_Bulldog), auch wenn es die Firma so schon sehr lange nicht mehr gibt. Und wenn's laut und stinkig mit überdimensionalen dreckigen Reifen vor mir her knattert, dann denke ich noch immer instinktiv "*#!?x+*# Bulldog".

Comment: @Stephie    Beachte, dass Jan nicht "Bulldog" schrieb sondern bairisch korrekt "Buidog." Was ich für eine sinnvolle Differenzierung halte, denn eine Bulldogge ist ein hässlicher Hund, ein Buidog ein praktisches landwirtschaftliches Zugfahrzeug.

Comment: @chirlu    Meine Verwandtschaft, die mehrere solcher Geräte besitzt (leicht südlich der Schwäbischen Alb) sagt entweder "Bulldog" oder "Schlepper".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann also hier (s.o.) *ist* es ein  “Bulldog” - Schwäbisch gschwätzt halt

Answer (score -4):

Das Schild ist einfach falsch.

Richtig müsste es so heißen:

[image]

Comment: Das wurde weder gefragt, noch steht es zur Debatte, denn das Schild ist gesetzlich geregelt und existiert genau so. Streng genommen müßte es sowieso " *darf überholt werden*" heißen, denn eine ganze Kolonne von Traktoren dürfte man vermutlich doch nicht überholen.

Comment: "Gesetzlich geregelt" heißt ja nicht, dass es deshalb grammatisch-orthographisch unzweifelfhaft sein muss. - Aus der Verwendung des Plurals ergibt sich übrigens nicht unbedingt, dass zwangsläufig mehrere Traktoren in Reihe überholt werden dürfen. Der Plural wird hier ja mehr in einem generischen Sinne verwendet. Voll ausnotiert müsste das Schild wohl so heißen:  "Landwirtschaftliche Zugfahrzeuge dürfen anders als andere Fahrzeuge prinzipiell überholt werden (sofern andere Gründe nicht entgegenstehen)".

Comment: Früher hieß es (glaube ich) ganz einfach nur   *frei*.

Comment: @takkt  Ich meine "Landwirtschaftliche Fahrzeuge frei" ist ein Zusatz zu Schildern, die die Wegbenützung mit Kraftfahrzeugen grundsätzlich verbieten. Ausnahme dann eben Landwirtschaftsmaschinen.

Comment: Der Beitrag ist hier wirklich fehl am Platze. Unabhängig von der Frage, wer sich mit welchem Recht dazu aufschwingen kann, eine alltägliche und offenbar sogar gesetzlich normierte Sprachverwendung als falsch zu bewerten, ist das hier wirklich ein obiter dictum. Die eigentliche Frage wird dabei nicht einmal gestreift. Daher gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: @Takkat (1): Wieso sollte sich aus dem Schild ergeben, dass mehrere Traktoren nicht überholt werden dürfen? Das kann ja auch schlecht eine offene Frage sein. Ich kenne kein Verbot, welches solche Unterschiede bei der Anzahl macht, etwa LKWs zu überholen. Dass man nur einen Traktor überholen darf könnte auch interpretiert werden, dass man auf dem Streckenabschnitt insgesamt nur einen überholen darf, selbst wenn man zwischen zweien einschert.

Comment: @userunknown: das ist doch ganz klar: denn in diesem Fall würde §32(2) mit §27(2) der StVO gelten. Das Schild ist allein schon deshalb **falsch**, weil "****" gar kein amtlich anerkanntes Schriftzeichen des deutschen Alphabets ist. Ich wüßte beispielsweise gar nicht, wie ich diesen Buchstaben aussprechen soll. Das kann man meines Wissens auch **nirgends** nachschlagen! Ich würde spontan darauf tippen, dass es [**Trecker**](https://dwds.de/wb/Trecker) heißen könnte, aber ich mag da **ganz falsch** liegen. Durch den Plural wird endlich mal gesagt, dass die Ausnahme nicht **nur einmal** gilt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, etwas präziser, es soll denn "**Die** Traktoren dürfen überholt werden" sein ;-) Der Geschlechtswort muss immer da sein, oder? Es handelt sich aber nur um einen Straßenschild, deshalb sind der Geschlechtswort und die Plural der Kürze halber weggelassen.

Comment: @Takkat: Der Trecker steht für eine Klasse von etwas, nicht für die Größe der Menge. Das Fußgängerüberwegbild zeigt auch nur einen Fußgänger, das Radwegschild nur ein Rad. Das ist ein durchgängiges Muster bei Verkehrsschildern. Was Du mit Buchstaben willst ist mir unklar. Wenn, dann steht das Symbol für ein Wort oder eine Wortgruppe.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: Nein, ein Geschlechtswort (ich denke Du meinst Artikel) muss nicht immer da sein. Stünde da "die Traktoren", dann müssten auch immer welche da sein, damit man sich nicht fragen kann "welche Traktoren". Nur ist eben die Zahl nicht bestimmt und wie stellt man eine beliebige Zahl Traktoren da? Wären 2 aufgemalt könnte man ebenso gut meinen, man dürfe nur genau 2 überholen, nicht mehr und nicht weniger. Eher könnte man es lesen als "Ein Traktor darf überholt werden" mit Betonung auf Traktor, nicht *ein*,

Comment: @Takkat » frei« (analog »Anlieger frei«) würde bedeuten, dass die entsprechenden Fahrzeuge die einzigen sind, für die das Verbot nicht gilt – oder anders ausgedrückt: » dürfen überholen«. Kleiner, aber feiner Unterschied ;)