# Why is it just "werden" and not "werden sein"?

Tags: colloquial, standard-german

Ich habe den nächsten Satz in einer Geschichte gefunden. Er kommt in einer Partyeinladung vor.

> Gefeiert wird beim nächsten Vollmond auf X Island.

Dieser Satz ist jedoch nicht der Einzige dieser Art, den ich jemals gelesen habe. Jedes Mal fragt ich mich, was der Unterschied zwischen "werden" und "werden sein" ist. Warum kann man den Satz nicht mit "werden sein" schreiben? Oder kann man doch, aber kann es auch weglassen?

In English, it could be translated as "It will be celebrated in the next full moon on the x island". In Spanish "Será celebrado/Se celebrará en la siguiente luna llena en la isla x".

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25746/d%c3%bcrfen-%c3%bcberholt-werden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Du denkst anscheinend, dass "werden" das Futur anzeigt, und Du vermisst ein "sein" um Passiv anzuzeigen. Im Deutschen wird(!) aber das Passiv mit "werden" gebildet, nicht mit "sein".

> Das Fest wird gefeiert.

Das ist Passiv und Gegenwart. Im Deutschen wird die Gegenwartsform häufig auch für Ereignisse in der Zukunft benutzt.

Wenn Du Futur benutzen möchtest, heißt es:

> Gefeiert wird [Futur] beim nächsten Vollmond auf X Island werden [Passiv].

Das wäre aber unüblich.

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht helfen Dir einige Beispielsätze in korrektem Deutsch:

> Gefeiert wird beim nächsten Vollmond auf der Insel Norderney.

*The party will take place in the next full moon on Norderney Island.*

> Was ist denn hier passiert? - Es wird ein Fest gefeiert worden sein.

*Jesus, what happened here? - I suppose a party has been celebrated here.*

> Hier werden Feste gefeiert werden.

*Here, parties will be celebrated.*

Trotz aller Bemühungen schaffe ich es nicht, mir einen Satz auszudenken, in dem "werden sein" vorkommt - selbst in außergewöhnlichen Situationen mit außergewöhnlicher Wortreihenfolge. Alles was mir einfällt, erfordert "worden sein" (mit o).

Comment: Stimmt bei diesem Satz mit _»werden sein«_ die Grammatik? Ganz sicher bin ich mir nicht. _»Schon nach dem kleinsten Kleinerfolg will Eduard als klug gesehen werden sein.«_ / _»Als klug gesehen werden sein will Eduard schon nach dem kleinsten Kleinerfolg.«_

Comment: Sie werden ein Moderator sein.

Comment: @Pollitzer   Die beiden Sätze, die du anführst, sind grammatisch nicht regelgemäß. Grammatikmäßig richtig (aber stilistisch immer noch ungelenk) wären: *Schon nach dem kleinsten Minierfolg will Eduard als klug angesehen werden* / *Als klug angesehen werden will Eduard schon nach dem kleinsten Minierfolg.* - Interessant ist folgender Fall: *Eduard will schon immer als klug angesehen w**o**rden sein*, mit der speziellen Bedeutung: "Eduard behauptet, dass er schon immer als klug angesehen worden sei, aber ich zweifle in leicht spöttischer Weise dran".

Comment: P.S. Man könnte das Beispiel auch noch weiterspinnen und sich zu einem Satzungetüm versteigen wie: *Eduard will schon immer als klug angesehen werden gewollt haben.* Aber das ist dann nur noch eine grammatische Hirngymnastikübung.